# changing home directory in R

Tags: r

In R, if I use the command

```
write.csv(res,"~/table1_n500.csv")
```

, then the result is saved in `C:\Users\John Smith\Documents`.
But I expected it to be saved in `C:\Users\John Smith\`.

Can I change this home directory (referred by ~ mark) to `C:\Users\John Smith\`?

Comment: As others have pointed out, `setwd()` seems to be the best option here.  But if you truly need to change the home directory, refer to [FAQ 2.14](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f) for some clues.  You can check it by using `path.expand("~")`.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, i usually import data from a file (for example in the directory C:\Users\John Smith\DATA)

then i will set working directory as

```
setwd("C:/Users/John Smith/DATA")
```

While i want to save the output file in other directory like "C:\Users\John Smith" but not in the data folder.

so i will set relative working directory like

```
setwd("../")
```

And when you type `getwd()` 
you will get `[1] "C:/Users/John Smith"`

Wish this help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deal with this problem.

1.) Use the function `setwd()` to set the working directory (or home directory). All save and read commands will look for files in that working directory. I use this only sparingly, and for quick tiny project.

2.) A more preferred approach is to define a variable like `dataInputDir`, and use function `file.path(dataInputDir, <your filename>)` to generate a file path. The advantage is that if you are reading (writing) data from (to) multiple directories, you can do this more efficiently:

```
file.path(dataInputDir1, <your file or dir name>)
file.path(dataInputDir2, <your file or dir name>)
file.path(dataOutputDir1, <your file or dir name>)
file.path(dataOutputDir2, <your file or dir name>)
```

This approach is really handy for large complicated projects, and is highly recommended.
This is also helpful, if your program is to be executed on multiple platform like Windows, Mac, Linux. You'll have to change the directory location only at one place, and everything else will work smoothly.

Additionally, following functions/handles will be useful for dealing with directory names:

Quick fix:

```
setwd("../") # setwd to parent folder of current working directory (getwd())
```

More robust:

```
setwd(dirname(dataInputDir)) # Setwd to parent folder of dataInputDir
```